# Problem with align button in treeview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got something:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyService:Country}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfAreas}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    <Button Name="MyButton" Height="20" Content="Add Area"></Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

It works, but not nice way, because I want to have TextBox at middle hight of button.
Now it is at top hight of button.

for example:

NOW:

```
MYTEXTBOX ||||||||||||
          ||Add Area|| 
          ||||||||||||
```

Expected result

```
          ||||||||||||
MYTEXTBOX ||Add Area|| 
          ||||||||||||
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set VerticalAlignment to Center (instead of TextAlignment) like this:

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" ... />
```